# change the value of button in ajax when json is return some value

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am writing simple ajax code with javascript and jquery and getting the data in json format, If json is empty that time i want to change button value.

Comment: i think you just want to change the value of button if json data is not null

Comment: It's very simple you should search the community before posting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data is not null condition

```
success: function(data){
    if(data!=””)
        document.getElementByInnerHtml('ButtonId').value=”newValue”;
    }//end success
```